# Add a deep copy ctor to std::unique_ptr<my_type>

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, deep-copy, unique-ptr

I would like to store some `std::unique_ptr<my_type>` into a `std::vector`. Since `my_type` provides a `clone()` method it's quite straightforward to make deep copies of `my_type *`. The point is how to extend `std::unique_ptr` preserving all its functionalities while adding the copy ctor and the assignment operator. Inheritance? Templace specialization? Could you please provide a code snippet?

Comment: are you looking for a `value_ptr`? Several floating around on the *nets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a way to go:

```
struct my_type_ptr: public std::unique_ptr<my_type,std::default_delete<my_type>>{
  using unique_ptr::unique_ptr; //inheriting constructors

  //adding copy ctor and assigment operator      
  my_type_ptr(const my_type_ptr & o):
    unique_ptr<my_type,std::default_delete<my_type>>()
    { reset( o ? o->clone() : nullptr); } 
  my_type_ptr& operator=(const my_type_ptr & o)
    { reset( o ? o->clone() : nullptr); return *this; }
};
```

It compiles without any warning from gcc and clang, and valgrind doesn't report any memory leak while playing around with copies and vectors.

Comment: @Snps I tested something like this: `ptr2 = ptr1 = ptr1 = ptr1 = ptr2;` with valgrind memcheck and looks fine. The default deleter is explicitly specified because otherwise I cannot inherit constructors; I don't know exactly the dynamic for this, I just tried. If you don't have polymorphism you can just have the same pattern that you used in your answer avoiding the call to clone().

Comment: @Snps why would it leak? `reset` doesn't leak. It's ok *even if* clone throws, because no work is done before the cloning. The only part where this fails at is missing the null checks.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes thanks for pointing out the fail with nullptr. I fixed the code.

Comment: @DarioP I was wrong before, but I'm pretty sure your null check is not quite right yet. A reference can never bind to a `nullptr` so you don't have to check that. Maybe @R.MartinhoFernandes meant to check the return value of `clone`?

Comment: @Snps `unique_ptr`s can be null. Everything seems fine from here. If `clone` returns  null, the new pointer will be null as well.

Comment: @Snps That is not a reference, is the `operator bool()` provided by `std::unique_ptr`. The return value of `clone()` is of a covariant type of `my_type`.

Comment: @DarioP Ah ok, I can see now. Sorry about the fuss :)

Answer (score 9):

The purpose of `std::unique_ptr` is for it to be unique i.e. it shouldn't be copyable. That's why they made it to be move-only. It is used for representing unique ownership.

If you want to make a deep copy then let your copy constructor do its work, that's what it's for.

```
std::unique_ptr<my_type> ptr1{new my_type{}};      // Lets say you have this.

std::unique_ptr<my_type> ptr2{new my_type{*ptr1}}; // Make deep copy using copy ctor.
```

The purpose of the copy ctor is to make a deep copy. You don't need a clone method in C++.

Comment: Indeed making a deep copy the ownership remains unique. Of course I can do copies as you pointed out, but this won't allow me to store the pointers in a vector. The clone method is there because of polymorphism.

Comment: @DarioP Ok, now I understand what you're after. I might be wrong but couldn't you simply use a `std::shared_ptr` instead? It's copy-constructible and the vector doesn't even have to perform deep copies when moving/copying the elements.

Comment: @DarioP Of course, if you need to be able to copy the contents of the vector to e.g. another vector, then you need something else.

Comment: Indeed that's exactly the case: the whole vector have then to be copyable and the ownership has still to remain unique.

Comment: This maybe very old, but this solution is wrong. @Snps does not account for object slicing which occurs in the case where my_type is a base of some derived type held by the unique_ptr. This error won't be visible at compile time and would wreak havoc. OP is correct in using a clone method to maintain polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me as if boost::ptr_container would serve your needs here.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html