# To copy a vector of unique pointer into new vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, constants

When I compile the below code, I get a compilation error:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<boxIndex>> tmpVec;
for(const auto& it: hrzBoxTmpMap){
    for(const auto& it2: hrzBoxVec){
        std::copy_if(hrzBoxVec.begin(), hrzBoxVec.end(), tmpVec.begin(), [&](std::unique_ptr<boxIndex>& p)
        {
            return !(it.second == p->getTop() &&
                     it.first != p->getLeft() );
        });
    }
}
```

The compilation error is:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_algo.h: 

> In instantiation of ‘_OIter std::copy_if(_IIter, _IIter, _OIter,
> _Predicate) [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::unique_ptr<boxIndex>*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<boxIndex> > >; _OIter =
> __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::unique_ptr<boxIndex>*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<boxIndex> > >; _Predicate =
> smoothHrzIndexing(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<boxIndex>
> >&)::<lambda(std::unique_ptr<boxIndex>&)>]’: test_word_2.cpp:282:5:   required from here
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_algo.h:990:6:
> error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&
> std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&)
> [with _Tp = boxIndex; _Dp = std::default_delete<boxIndex>]’ In file
> included from
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/memory:86:0,
>                  from test_word_2.cpp:8: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/unique_ptr.h:263:19:
> error: declared here
```

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: You cant copy a unique_ptr you need to move them.

Comment: Do you want the new vector to have unique_ptrs to copies of the original objects?

Comment: I am aware of Moving unique pointers. But not sure where to place std::move in above statement. Pls confirm.

Comment: Neil, I want just new vector to hold the objects instead of old vector. That is, i would not need old vector anymore

Comment: Interesting problem. I don't know how to do this with std algorithm. There is copy_if but not move_if. You could swap the vectors and use remove_if on the new vector.

Comment: But, i am afraid copying vector is costly and I would not want it. I would prefer to iterate through my present vector(of unique pointers) and remove certain elements. I even tried below statement. But in vain. hrzBoxVec.erase(std::remove_if(hrzBoxVec.begin(), hrzBoxVec.end(), [&](std::unique_ptr<boxIndex> & p)
    {
        return std::find(hrzBoxTmpMap.begin(), hrzBoxTmpMap.end(), p.get())!= hrzBoxTmpMap.end();
    }   ), hrzBoxVec.end());

Comment: Just swap and remove_if, as suggested by @NeilKirk.

Comment: You don't need to copy the vector, swap is fast.

Comment: Although this issue is solved by properly moving the pointers, sometimes a copy is really wanted. Few hints here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535719/add-a-deep-copy-ctor-to-stdunique-ptrmy-type

Comment: `v2.swap(v1);` or you'll have to clone the objects pointed to.

Answer (score 7):

What you could do is to use `std::move_iterator<...>` using, e.g., something like below (this is a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) demonstrating the crucial point:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> boxVec;
    boxVec.emplace_back(new int(1));
    boxVec.emplace_back(new int(17));
    boxVec.emplace_back(new int(3));
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> tmpVec;
    std::copy_if(std::make_move_iterator(boxVec.begin()),
                 std::make_move_iterator(boxVec.end()),
                 std::back_inserter(tmpVec),
                 [&](std::unique_ptr<int> const& p){
                     return *p == 17; });
    for (auto const& x: boxVec) {
        (x? std::cout << *x: std::cout << "<null>") << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Dereferencing a `std::move_iterator<It>` will return a suitable rvalue of the iterator's value type. Since the rvalue is obtained using `std::move(*it)`, it is a reference. That is, the value isn't stolen until the value is actually moved. The comparison uses a `const&`, i.e., it won't steal the value. The assignment will become an rvalue assignment. The code also uses `std::back_inserter()` to arrange for enough elements to be in the destination.

I don't think this is really a solid solution but I also don't think there is an algorithm like `std::move_if()` (or a customization of any algorithm resulting in the same behavior). To really deal with conditionally moving objects I think you'd different access mechanism for the values passed into the predicate and the the way objects are assigned ([property maps](https://github.com/dietmarkuehl/kuhllib/wiki/STL-2.0) would address these issues but there is no proposal, yet, to add them to the C++ standard).

Comment: you could use `remove_copy_if` instead of `copy_if`, so the moved elements can be deleted from the old vector.

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct way of doing this, but you can chain some STL commands to achieve what you want:

- `std::stable_partition` or `std::partition` to split your container in half.
- `std::move` to move the values you want to move to your new vector
- `vector.erase` to delete the old, invalid unique_ptr

In the end you have a clean source vector (all moved, invalid entries are removed) and a clean target vector.

this can look something like that:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> source, target;
// ... fill data
auto it = std::stable_partition(begin(source),end(source),[](std::unique_ptr<int> const& val) {
    return *val < 3; // your negated condition
});
std::move(it,end(source),std::back_inserter(target));
source.erase(it,end(source));
```

[Here is a live example](http://ideone.com/ryOFEl)

Answer (score 0):

`std::unique_ptr` is **movable**, not *copyable*.
So, you can't use `std::copy_if()` with `unique_ptr` instances.

If you really want to use `std::copy_if()`, then you may use `std::shared_ptr` instead of `std::unique_ptr`, and then if you want to get rid of the old vector content, just destroy it using e.g. `vector::clear()`.

Or, if `shared_ptr` is too much overhead for you, or in any case you just want a vector of `unique_ptr`s, then you may want to consider doing an in-place removing of unwanted vector elements using `std::remove_if()` and the [*erase-remove* idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom).